# import excel data

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, import

I'm able to import my excel into datagridview successfully but only there is a little problem. There is only one column in my excel file and 10 rows. All 9 rows are in numbers and only the last row is a string.

all 10 show up in my datagridview but the last row is blank.

below is my function to open excel file

```
Public Sub OpenExcel(ByVal sFileName As String)
    Dim ConnectionStringTemplate As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
                                             "Data Source={0};" & _
                                             "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;" & _
                                             "HDR=No;IMEX=1"""

    Dim ConnectionString As String = String.Format(ConnectionStringTemplate, sFileName)
    Dim sqlSelect As String = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$];" 'Where you have a sheet named Sheet1 
    Dim WorkBook As New DataSet
    Dim ExcelAdapter As System.Data.Common.DataAdapter = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sqlSelect, ConnectionString)

    ExcelAdapter.Fill(WorkBook)

    frmMain.dgvCompose.DataSource = WorkBook.Tables(0)
    frmMain.staRecords.Text = "Total Records - " & frmMain.dgvCompose.RowCount
End Sub
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

You can enumarate datatable's rows with foreach and add all items to array or list.

It is more efficent than giving workbook's table to datasource directly. And if string row is exist, you can see when debugging.